# Cant enter VR Mode from Browser | Vive Pro, threejs

Tags: browser, htc-vive, webxr, steamvr, threejs-editor

I am stuck at developing a threejs VR project. If I look at https://threejs.org/examples/, the Button shows "VR not supported".

I can handle and debug via WebXR Extension. Connecting with SteamVR (HTC Pro Headset) seems impossible, not even the offical examples. Years ago I solved it via Firefox Reality Browser. But the browser got killed and is not available anymore. All alternatives seems not to work with the "Vive Pro". What I've tried so far:

- Reinstall SteamVR & Viveport.
- Changed Flags in Firefox:

```
dom.vr.always_support_vr
dom.vr.autoactivate.enabled
dom.vr.enabled
dom.vr.webxr.enabled
```

- Changed Flags in Chrome:

```
--force-webxr-runtime=openvr
--enable-features=openvr
--disable-features=XRSandbox
```

- I cant install the following Browser, because Pro wont support them:
  Vive Browser
  Wolvic Browser
- The Settings of both Firefox & Chrome allow VR-Content to be added and are not blocking.
- Disabling xr sandbox in the web browsers that provided the option to enable/disable xr sandbox
- Enscripted beta versions of SteamVR
- Changed NVidia Power Management for Firefox to maximum performance
- If I select F12 > WebXR the HTC Vive, it allows me to enter Vr in the Browser. But the controls are only available in the DevTools. With unselecting the Vive Pro in Devtools, VR is not supported anymore.

Had anybody else this issue in the last months and knows a Fix for this? All I can find on the internet is years ago. I am infinitely grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
Only option at the moment (7.2023) for me is with google canary, its different to chrome and fixes the bridge between openxr and steamvr:
https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/

the support of htc vive wrote to me, so theres a tiny hope left to get something in Viveport:
Unfortunately, there are no VR web browser apps for PCVR devices on Viveport at the moment. Our team is still finding a suitable replacement and hopefully this will be resolved soon.